# Access JSON field starting with "@" - PHP MongoDB library

Tags: php, json, mongodb, character-encoding, php-mongodb

I have a MongoDB database with a collection composed by **persons** that follows this pattern

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3be781575621b1e1c7512d"),
    "@id" : "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/12749587-539f-359f-a48a-e3a2279c8fa8",
    "@type" : "foaf:Person",
    "name" : "Gallenga, Romeo"
```

and another collection composed by **items** like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3be71b575621b1e1c73f24"),
    "@id" : "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/000000017103",
    "@type" : [
            "bibo:MultiVolumeBook",
            "bibo:Book"
    ],
    "creator" : [
            "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/9959464b-24e6-338f-b79a-5705848861cd",
            "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/22ef493f-52ed-3b13-9756-03db125128e1",
            "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/adc7ca8d-ebb5-3879-bb76-38f7344a978d",
            "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/3a483833-4ada-30a6-8157-f4c61c6daf47"
    ],
    "identifier" : "000000017103",
    "title" : "Replica della formella del 14 sec. del campanile di Giotto raffigurante uno studio medico",        
}
```

I'm working with PHP 5.6 using MongoDB library.

#### Goal

I want to query for **items** that have a particular **creator** (that obviously is a **person**).
Through the  query (that works)

```
$authorlist=$pcollection->find(['name'=>$pregex],['projection'=>['_id'=>0,'@id'=>1,'name'=>1]]);
```

involving the regular expression **$pregex** , I retrieved a projection (cointaning the **@id** and **name** fields) of the person, then I tried to write the following query to obtain matches beetween the field **creator** of the **items** and **@id** field of the **persons**

```
  $documentlist=$icollection->find(['creator'=>($person->@id)]);
```

but it didn't work because PHP don't accept field starting with **@** (IDE says "expected field name").
I also tried

```
$documentlist=$icollection->find(['creator'=>($person->'@id')]);
```

but it didn't work.
So, **what's a way to access a JSON field that starts with "@" in PHP?**

Comment: `$person->{'@id'}`?

Comment: It works, if you rewrite it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it's already a duplicate, but accessing fields with non-regular names usually done as:

```
$person->{'strange-field-name'};
// for your case it is:
$person->{'@id'}
```